# CakePHP - Call to a member function search() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, cakephp-2.0

i created a NamesController.php in my cakephp installation and i created a search function:

```
public function search($api_key = null,$domain = null,$keywords = null,$country = null,$type = null) {
        $result = $this->Mails->search($keywords,$country,$type);
        return $result;
}
```

but this returns me an error:

```
 Call to a member function search() on a non-object
```

ps:MailsController.php also contains a search function,which works well.

Why this turns me out this error? What am i actually doing wrong?

Thank ya in advance!

Comment: have you verified that `Mails` exists and is an object? var_dump($this); and make sure there is a `Mails` member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are doing `$this->Mails->search` then search function should be in your **Mail model not controller**. If you want to access `Mails` controller's function from `Names` controller then do:

```
//names controller
App::import('Controller', 'Mails');
class NamesController extends AppController {
....
public function search($api_key = null,$domain = null,$keywords = null,$country = null,$type = null) {
    $mails = new MailsController();
    $result = $mails->search($keywords,$country,$type);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: -1 `new MailsController()` ? calling another controller is generally an indicator of bad architecture (methods in a controller that should be in a model). That said, the right way to do so is with `requestAction` not by directly creating a new controller instance

Answer (score 0):

Your result is correct, because you did not declare this variable.

Comment: please provide a proper answer